# R inequality operator error?

Tags: r, inequality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Numeric comparison difficulty in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769510/numeric-comparison-difficulty-in-r)

I'm using R 2.15.2 and found something like an unusual but serious error in R inequality operator.

```
> 0.015 -0.005 
[1] 0.01
> 0.015 - 0.005 == 0.01
[1] FALSE
> 0.025 - 0.005 == 0.02
[1] TRUE
```

Is this possible?

it only happens when I compare `0.015 - 0.005` with `0.01`.

Any ideas?

Try this with your computer and see this really happens!

Thanks, then what should I do wit inequality?

```
> 0.015 - 0.005 < 0.01 
[1] TRUE 
> 0.025 - 0.005 < 0.02 
[1] FALSE 
>
```

Comment: R FAQ 7.31 http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f

Comment: Thanks, but then I have no idea to explain this. 
    > 0.025 - 0.005 == 0.02 
    [1] TRUE

Comment: The take away is don't use `==` to compare floating point numbers. use `isTRUE(all.equal(x, y))` instead.

Comment: see this question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769510/numeric-comparison-difficulty-in-r/2769822#2769822