# Result from Cor() in R doesn't logically evaluate as I'd expect

Tags: r, logic, correlation

I'm trying to find a good way to test whether or not the correlation between two vectors is perfect (or NA.)  I've tried lots of different methods, but I'm having a similar problem with all of them, namely that the result of correlation doesn't evaluate in the way I'd expect.

This is my latest example:

```
foo1 <- c(4, NA, 6, NA)   
foo2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
set  <- c(-1, 1, NA)
correlation <- cor(foo1, foo2, use = "na.or.complete")  # Result: 1
correlation %in% set  # Should be TRUE, is FALSE
correlation == 1      # Should also be TRUE, but is FALSE
```

is.numeric(correlation) is TRUE.  The only value I can see in it or around it is 1.  Then whyyy in the world does this not work?

```
set  <- c('-1', '1', NA)
```

This works, but I'm not sure why, and I'm worried there are ways that it might fail because I clearly don't understand what's going on with the returned value.

Any insight at all would be helpful!

Comment: `all.equal(correlation,1)` is `TRUE` ... taking a look at R FAQ 7.31 might be useful.

Comment: Thanks!  I knew about all.equal, but I couldn't manage to find a way to get it working with NAs in the mix, or the possibility of it being -1, which is why I was hoping to manage it differently.

Comment: I think if you've developed a solution to your problem you should post it as an answer rather than as a part of your question. (You are allowed and in fact encouraged to answer your own questions.)

Comment: if (reputation <= 10){print("We don't trust you enough to answer your own questions within 8 hours.")}  Let's be honest, when my code makes the world explode sometime around iteration 5000, I think we'll all be greatful for that rule.

Comment: now your reputation is high enough ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, you can make sure that they are close enough to your set:

```
mytol <- 1e-10
set <- set[1:2]
any(abs(correlation - set) <= mytol)|is.na(correlation) # TRUE
```

It's to do with floats and tolerance, I guess. I'm not sure what the standard reference is, but here's one of them: [Numeric comparison difficulty in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769510/numeric-comparison-difficulty-in-r)

1 is not really 1; if you wanted an integer (and here I guess you shouldn't), you could use `1L`. Vectors created like `1:3` and `seq(1,3)` are also integers. Look at `?integer` and `?numeric` for more information. Strangely, I can't find a doc page that covers the differences between the classes.

EDIT: I split off the check for NA because, as the OP pointed out, it didn't work.

Comment: That's a really good thing to know -- I hadn't considered floating point issues, really. 

In this specific circumstance, it doesn't handle the comparison against NA, though, since it does that whole R thing where NA is like the plague and if anything touches NA it suddenly becomes NA. :)

I guess for 1 and -1, I could test it in that way, and have a secondary test for NA, but I don't really know how that might affect efficiency -- this is error checking for a simulation, so I'll be running it 10k times or so.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I forgot about the NA weirdness. I've edited the answer so that it should do the right check now. I guess for your simulation, you can put the correlations into a vector and just run this at the end. I don't think it should be too costly...

Answer (score 2):

I think this is basically FAQ 7.31, but "how do I see if a value is within a set (within tolerance)" requires a slight extension of the standard "just use `all.equal()`" answer ...

```
test <- function(x) {
          isTRUE(all.equal(x,-1)) || 
            isTRUE(all.equal(x,1)) || is.na(x)
}
test(1-1e-14)  ## TRUE
test(NA)       ## TRUE
test(0.88)      ## FALSE
```

is the most precise solution to your question, although I can see that it would get difficult if you had a much longer list of candidates ... since `isTRUE(all.equal(1,NA))` is `FALSE` (as is convenient) perhaps

```
test <- function(x,candidates=c(-1,1,NA), ...) {
    any(sapply(lapply(candidates,all.equal,target=x,...),
               isTRUE))
}
test(1-1e-6)    ## FALSE
test(1-1e-6,tolerance=1e-4)  ## TRUE
```

The one wrinkle here is that `isTRUE(all.equal(NA,NaN))` is **not** `TRUE`, so one might want to build `is.na()` (which tests for either `NA` or `NaN`) in here somewhere, or include `NaN` in the list of candidates.

Comment: Oh man, I didn't even realize R had `NaN`s! One more headache.

Comment: Oh geez.  Now I have to consider those guys, too.

Comment: No, you've already got it covered. `is.na()` tests for *either* `NA` or `NaN` (and for future reference, `is.finite()` also checks for `Inf` and `-Inf` ...)

Comment: That's the best news I've heard all day!  :D

Answer (score 1):

You people were super helpful.  For the interested, here's what the final result is, although I clearly have to play with my tolerances a little bit more.

```
corrIsOkay <- function(x, y){
  correlation  <- cor(x, y, use = "na.or.complete")
  if ((1 - abs(correlation)) <= .01 | is.na(correlation)){
    print(correlation)
    return(FALSE)
  }
  return(TRUE) 
}
```

It's a lot wordier than I would have liked, since my original "solution" fit inside an if statement by itself, but now I just call this function in the if statement.

```
makeMvMissing <- function(data) {
  repeat {
      x <- makeMissing(data)[, 1]
      y <- makeMissing(data, variable.missing = "y")[, 2]
      if (corrIsOkay(x, y)){
        break
      }
    }
  return(data.frame(x, y))
}
```