# Upper interval limits in function 'cut'

Tags: r, floating-point, double

I’d like to class a data frame in a certain way in `R`.
Assume to have a data frame like the following:

```
> data = sample(1:500, 5000, replace = TRUE)
```

In order to class this data frame I’m making these classes:

```
> data.cl = cut(data, breaks = c(seq(0,100,by=10), 200, 350, 480, 500))
> table(data.cl)
data.cl
   (0,10]   (10,20]   (20,30]   (30,40]   (40,50] 
      102        80        87       113       117 
  (50,60]   (60,70]   (70,80]   (80,90]  (90,100] 
      101        89        95       106       104 
(100,200] (200,350] (350,480] (480,500] 
     1002      1492      1318       194
```

If I want `0` to be included I’d just have to add `include.lowest = TRUE`:

```
> data.cl = cut(data, breaks = c(seq(0,100,by=10), 200, 350, 480, 500),
+ include.lowest = TRUE)
    > table(data.cl)
data.cl
   [0,10]   (10,20]   (20,30]   (30,40]   (40,50] 
      102        80        87       113       117 
  (50,60]   (60,70]   (70,80]   (80,90]  (90,100] 
      101        89        95       106       104 
(100,200] (200,350] (350,480] (480,500] 
     1002      1492      1318       194
```

In this example this doesn’t show any difference, because `0` isn’t occuring in this data frame at all. But if it would, e.g. `4` times, there would be `106` instead of `102` elements in class `[0,10]`:

```
> data.cl = cut(data, breaks = c(seq(0,100,by=10), 200, 350, 480, 500),
+ include.lowest = TRUE)
    > table(data.cl)
data.cl
   [0,10]   (10,20]   (20,30]   (30,40]   (40,50] 
      106        80        87       113       117 
  (50,60]   (60,70]   (70,80]   (80,90]  (90,100] 
      101        89        95       106       104 
(100,200] (200,350] (350,480] (480,500] 
     1002      1492      1318       194
```

There is another option in changing class limits. The default option for `cut()` is `right = FALSE`. If you change it to `right = TRUE` you’ll get:

```
> data.cl = cut(data, breaks = c(seq(0,100,by=10), 200, 350, 480, 500),
+ include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE)
> table(data.cl)
data.cl
   [0,10)   [10,20)   [20,30)   [30,40)   [40,50) 
       92        81        87       111       118 
  [50,60)   [60,70)   [70,80)   [80,90)  [90,100) 
      103        89        94       103       103 
[100,200) [200,350) [350,480) [480,500] 
     1003      1497      1320       199
```

`include.lowest` now becomes “`include.highest`” at the price of changing class limits and thus returning different amounts of class members in some classes, because of a slight shift in class limits.
But if I want to have the data frame

```
> data.cl = cut(data, breaks = c(seq(0,100,by=10), 200, 350, 480, 500))
> table(data.cl)
data.cl
   (0,10]   (10,20]   (20,30]   (30,40]   (40,50] 
      102        80        87       113       117 
  (50,60]   (60,70]   (70,80]   (80,90]  (90,100] 
      101        89        95       106       104 
(100,200] (200,350] (350,480] (480,500) 
     1002      1492      1318       194
```

to **exclude** `500`, too, what shall I do?
Of course, one can say: “Just write `data.cl = cut(data, breaks = c(seq(0,100,by=10), 200, 350, 480, 499))` instead of `data.cl = cut(data, breaks = c(seq(0,100,by=10), 200, 350, 480, 500))`, because you’re dealing with integer numbers.”
Well, that’s right, but what would be if this wouldn’t be the case and I’d use floats instead? How can I exclude `500` then?

Comment: Warning: these are not "classes."  "Class" has a very specific meaning in programming, and in `R` in particular.  Anyway,  you don't have to use `cut` ; if all else fails, split your dataset using `plyr` tools or a series of `data.x <- data[data>480 & data <=500]` vs, say, `data.y<=data[data>480 & data<500]`

Comment: It's easier of you exclude `500` and then use `cut`. You can do something like `data[data==500] <- Inf`. But beware of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769510/numeric-comparison-difficulty-in-r).