# Rounding issue in all.equal

Tags: r

I am reading through [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), and have run into something I do not understand. In addition to section 8.2.23 in the Inferno, there have been some good questions on comparing floating point numbers: [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769510/numeric-comparison-difficulty-in-r/2769822#2769822).

However, I am still running into a problem using `all.equal`. Using the default `all.equal` I get the results (mostly) as I would expect.

```
> all.equal(2,1.99999997)
[1] "Mean relative difference: 1.5e-08"
> all.equal(2,1.99999998) #I expected FALSE here
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(2,1.99999999)
[1] TRUE
```

I am not sure why at 1.99999998 the function returns `TRUE`, but that is not as concerning as the following behavior where I specified the tolerance level:

```
> all.equal(2,1.98,tolerance=0.01) #Behaves as expected
[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.01"
> all.equal(2,1.981,tolerance=0.01) #Does not behave as expected
[1] TRUE
```

Furthermore,

```
> all.equal(2,1.980000000001,tolerance=0.01)
[1] TRUE
```

But if we compute:

```
> diff(c(1.981,2))
[1] 0.019
```

and clearly,

```
> diff(c(1.981,2)) >= 0.01
[1] TRUE
```

So, why is `all.equal` unable to distinguish 2 and 1.981 with a tolerance of 0.01?

**EDIT**

From the documentation: *Numerical comparisons for scale = NULL (the default) are done by first computing the mean absolute difference of the two numerical vectors. If this is smaller than tolerance or not finite, absolute differences are used, otherwise relative differences scaled by the mean absolute difference.*

Here I do not understand the behavior. I can see that `diff(1.981,2)` is not finite:

```
> sprintf("%.25f",diff(c(1.981,2)))
[1] "0.0189999999999999058530875"
```

But then what does it get scaled by? When each vector is of length one, the mean absolute difference should equal the difference of the two numbers, and dividing by the mean absolute difference would give 1. Clearly, I am understanding the logic here wrong.

Comment: from the help file: `all.equal(x, y)` is a utility to compare R objects x and y testing ‘near equality’ (note: near )

Comment: `is.finite` indicates which elements are finite (not infinite and not missing) or infinite (as in `Inf` and `-Inf`, not repeating decimals!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has to do with floating point accuracy. The manual isn't entirely clear at first glance, but in your example the `mean absolute difference` of `2-1.981` is `0.019` which is `>` `0.01`, the `tolerance`. `scale` is also `NULL`. Therefore the comparison made is the relative difference scaled by the mean absolute difference. Eh?!

Using `tolerance` implies that you care about the magnitude of the numbers involved. [**Relative difference**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference#Definitions) accounts for not how big the difference is (absolute terms), but how great it is, *relative* to the numbers being compared. Given the example in the link, the difference between 5 and 6 is more *significant* (I use the term loosely) than between `1,000,000,000` and `1,000,000,001`.

So if the **relative difference** between the two numbers is less than `tolerance` the numbers are considered equal. For two single numbers (as in this example) the relative difference is given by:

```
( current - target ) / current
```

Which is

```
( 2 - 1.981 ) / 2 == 0.0095
```

The tolerance you specified is `0.01` therefore the numbers are considered equal because the relative difference is less than this. The difference between these numbers `±` the relative difference also just happens to be the smallest representable floating point number!

```
identical( abs( ( 2 - 0.0095 ) - ( 1.981 + 0.0095 ) ) , .Machine$double.eps )
[1] TRUE
```

Now try:

```
all.equal( 2 , 1.981 , 0.00949999999999 )
[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.0095"
```

Answer (score 6):

This happens because in this case `all.equal` checks relative differences. If you set `scale=1`, i.e. no scaling, absolute comparisons will be made and `all.equal` behaves as you are expecting.

For further details see the documentation on the `scale` parameter.

```
> all.equal(2,1.980000000001,tolerance=0.01)
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(2,1.980000000001,tolerance=0.01,scale=1)
[1] "Mean scaled difference: 0.02"
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about scale. However, I am still stumped by the default behavior with `scale = NULL`.

Comment: "Numerical comparisons for scale = NULL (the default) are done by first computing the mean absolute difference of the two numerical vectors. If this is smaller than tolerance or not finite, absolute differences are used, otherwise relative differences scaled by the mean absolute difference." (documentation) -- OK, actually I don't get it either.