# >= not working, R

Tags: r, if-statement, double, logic

I am running the code below. The function Ax returtns the value 1. But the ifelse statement does not recognize that Ax==1.

I've tried making the output of the function double-precision and all numeric values double. This hasn't worked.

I was hoping: 
1) to get help troubleshooting this specific case 
2) to get tips on how to avoid this problem in the future

```
Axfun<-function(beta,gamma,a,b,g,H0stud,Wh,Wi){ 
  ((b*beta + g*gamma)*(1 + 2*g*gamma)*(1 + gamma + b*((-beta)*(1 + gamma) + a*(-1 + beta)*(1 + g*gamma)))*H0stud*Wi)/
    ((-1 + b*beta)*(1 + gamma)*((-g)*gamma*(1 + 2*g*gamma)*Wi + b*beta*((-1 + g*gamma*(-2 + H0stud) + H0stud)*Wh - (1 + g*gamma)*H0stud*Wi)))
}

Ax<-Axfun(2^1,
          2^0,
          2^0,
          2^-3,
          2^-1,
          1,
          1,
          0.4)

ifelse(Ax>=1, 0, Ax)
```

Comment: Check out `?all.equal`, e.g. `all.equal(Ax, 1)`, which allows differences within `tolerance`.

Comment: And see also these SO posts: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/489704), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2769510/489704), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18794129/489704).

Comment: Also Circle 1 of [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the `>=`, your problem is that 1 is not really one.
Try this

```
Ax >= 1
[1] FALSE
Ax == 1
[1] FALSE
```

and

```
format(Ax, digits = 20)
[1] "0.99999999999999977796"
```

#### Edit: A possible Solution

As solutions to your problems you can return the final result of your function to an object and then use it as the `ceiling` function.

If you have to work with such results maybe a read of the Circle 1 of the R Inferno is a good thing to do. You can find it [here](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).