# In R, 0.1*2 results in 0.2000000000000000111022?

Tags: r

After setting `options(digits=22)` in R, I noticed that when issuing `0.1*2` in the R console, I get `0.2000000000000000111022` as a result.

Any ideas why?

Regards.

Comment: Probably [**R FAQ 7.31**](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and [**this Q&A**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal/9508558#9508558) are relevant here.

Comment: Also , please read this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769510/numeric-comparison-difficulty-in-r