# How do I resolve the following contradiction which is occured in R?

Tags: r, sqrt

The problem is the following:

```
sqrt (3) ^ 2 == 3
```

When the R compiler evaluates this line of code it gives the following result:

```
> sqrt (3) ^ 2 == 3
[1] FALSE
```

But this expression can not be FALSE because of the following: (sqrt(x))^2 = x.
What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are these numbers not equal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) also you can have a look here: [Numeric comparison difficulty in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769510/numeric-comparison-difficulty-in-r)

Comment: ``all.equal(sqrt (3) ^ 2, 3)``

Comment: And `format(sqrt (3) ^ 2, digits=22)`