# Why doesn't all.equal work within dplyr's mutate function?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following code:

```
library(dplyr)       
patientID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
age <- c(25, 34, 28, 52)
diabetes <- c("Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type1")
status <- c("Poor", "Improved", "Excellent", "Poor")
patientdata <- data.frame(patientID, age, diabetes, status)
myf <- function(patientID, age, diabetes, status) { isTRUE(all.equal(age, 34))}
mutate(patientdata, isAge34 = myf(patientID, age, diabetes, status))
```

I wrote `myf` to return `TRUE` for the row where `age == 34`, but this doesn't work:

```
  patientID age diabetes    status isAge34
1         1  25    Type1      Poor   FALSE
2         2  34    Type2  Improved   FALSE
3         3  28    Type1 Excellent   FALSE
4         4  52    Type1      Poor   FALSE
```

Why didn't this work? Did I doing something wrong?

---

**EDIT:** This is a contrived, simplified example. In reality, I have much more complicated logic inside of my function.

My motivation for asking:

- I thought that I was supposed to prefer `isTRUE(all.equal())` over `==` because that's the R way of doing things.

[Reference 1](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/Comparison.html), [Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/109941):

> For numerical and complex values, remember == and != do not allow for the finite representation of fractions, nor for rounding error. Using all.equal with identical is almost always preferable. See the examples.

Comment: Your function doesn't make any sense. If you want to compare `age` why are you passing all the rest of the columns? If this a function, why did you hardcoded the variable names in the first place? Either you could just do `patientdata %>% mutate(age == 34)` or `myf <- function(x) x == 34 ; patientdata %>% mutate(myf(age))`.

Comment: I agree with @DavidArenburg but as far as your function goes, it will work if you `Vectorize` it (`myf <- Vectorize(myf)`)

Comment: @DavidArenburg: But I thought that `isTRUE(all.equal())` was preferred over `==`.

Comment: @JimG. 1- `all.equal()` is not vectorized- see Sotos comment. 2- Do you have any reference for that statement (I would love to see it)? You basically could stick with your approach (if efficiency doesn't matter) but *you need to write the function in a reasonable manner*, for instance `myf <- function(x) isTRUE(all.equal(x, 34)) ; patientdata %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(myf(age))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg: I just edited my question and cited two references. All in all, I'm not really fussy about a certain approach. I'm just trying to do things "the R way".

Comment: @JimG. You are talking about floating points, not integers (like in your case). And the main problem not with the general approach (which can be used as pointed in my comment)- rather with logic of your function - which isn't a function really

Comment: @DavidArenburg: OK. So if they were floating point numbers, I suppose that I would need to use an alternative approach (like the one you described with `rowwise()`)?

Comment: I think setting some tolerance level and keep it vectorized is a better approach. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769510/numeric-comparison-difficulty-in-r). Though I'm not an authority in any matter, so it's up to you to decide. My main complaint is regarding your code- not the actual approach

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Very interesting. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@DavidArenburg said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747503/why-doesnt-all-equal-work-within-dplyrs-mutate-function#comment66791743_39747503), `all.equal()` is not vectorized.

The following code will work:

```
mutate(patientdata, isAge34 = age == 34)
```

Comment: I don't think defining this function is necessary (or reasonable- the only purpose of the function is to check the equality of it argument to a fixed value). @DavidArenburg suggestion above of using `mutate(patientdata, isAge34 = age == 34)` works and is a lot simpler.

Comment: @ddiez: I agree. Please see my revision.

Comment: This works for integers but you can fall into the classic floating point trap! http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Answer (score 6):

The point of `all.equal` is to check for *near equality*, most commonly for use with *floating point numbers*. Comparisons with `==` will not give reliable results for floating point numbers (the [link](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) provided by @Andew's comment explains this). **Therefore the accepted answer is not actually a correct solution**, because the dataframe described in the original post specifies the `age` variable as `numeric` (**not** `integer`!).

`dplyr` provides the `near` function, which is basically a vectorized version of `all.equal` that works with `mutate`.

```
mutate(patientdata, isAge34 = near(age, 34))
```