# R Writing a function input equal integer,but input maybe NA

Tags: r

I want to write a function,Determine the input is equal to 1,
but The input maybe includes (NA NULL).

```
> equals1 <- function(x){
+   return(x==1)
+ }

> equals1(1)
[1] TRUE
> equals1(Inf)
[1] FALSE
> equals1(NA)
[1] NA
> equals1(NULL)
logical(0)
> equals1(NaN)
[1] NA
```

I want is as follows：

```
equals1<-function(x){
   if(is.null(x)){
     return(FALSE)
     }else if(is.na(x)){
       return(FALSE)
     }else{return(x==1)}
}
c(equals1(1),equals1(Inf),equals1(NA),equals1(NULL),equals1(NaN))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Is there a simple function?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`identical` can do this.

```r
identical(1, 1)
#> [1] TRUE
identical(1, Inf)
#> [1] FALSE
identical(1, NA)
#> [1] FALSE
identical(1, NULL)
#> [1] FALSE
identical(1, NaN)
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

---

You could write a simple wrapper like this:

```r
equals1 <- function(x)identical(x, 1)

c(equals1(1),equals1(Inf),equals1(NA),equals1(NULL),equals1(NaN))
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

according [Numeric comparison difficulty in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769510/numeric-comparison-difficulty-in-r)
this function can do it easily. note that identical(tan(pi/4),1) returns false.

```
    identical(tan(pi/4),1)
    #[1] FALSE
    eq<-function(x,y){
    isTRUE(all.equal(x, y))
    }
    eq(tan(pi/4),1)
    #[1] TRUE
    eq(3,1)
   #[1] FALSE
     eq(NA,1)
   #[1] FALSE
    eq(1, NaN)
   #[1] FALSE
    eq(1,1)
   #[1] TRUE
    eq(Inf,1)
  #[1] FALSE
    eq(NA,1)
  #[1] FALSE
    eq(NULL,1)
   #[1] FALSE
```