# Even after converting my file as factor why does my output give factor(0) 30956 Levels?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am new to R and working on the below dataset:

I have a file called zippopinc

## Repex:

```
head(zippopinc)

  Year         Zip     Total_Population Median_Income   City State
1 1 2017 ZCTA5 00601            17599         11757  Adjuntas    PR
2 2 2017 ZCTA5 00602            39209         16190    Aguada    PR
3 3 2017 ZCTA5 00603            50135         16645 Aguadilla    PR
4 4 2017 ZCTA5 00606             6304         13387   Maricao    PR
5 5 2017 ZCTA5 00610            27590         18741    Anasco    PR
6 6 2017 ZCTA5 00612            62566         17744   Arecibo    PR
  Poptoincomeratio
       1.4968955
       2.4218036
       3.0120156
       0.4709046
       1.4721733
       3.5260370
```

## poptoincomeratio is basically Total_Population/Median_Income

My objective is to find which zip code has the highest Poptoincomeratio:

My input:

```
max(sapply(zippopinc$Poptoincomeratio, max))
```

Output:

```
4.454182
```

So I tried,

```
zippopinc$Zip[demograph_ratio$Poptoincomeratio == 4.454182]
```

But this gave me:

```
factor(0)
30956 Levels
```

## I then tried to convert zipopinc as a factor but got the below error:

```
> as.factor(zippopinc)
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find which zip code has the highest Poptoincomeratio do :

```
zippopinc$Zip[which.max(zippopinc$Poptoincomeratio)]
```

The reason why it doesn't yield you any output with current approach is because there are some limitations in comparing floating point values. Read more here

- [Numeric comparison difficulty in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769510/numeric-comparison-difficulty-in-r)
- [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Even for the shared example, we can see that 3.5260370 is the highest value in `Poptoincomeratio` column but when we compare the values we get

```
zippopinc$Poptoincomeratio == 3.5260370
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

but if you use `which.max` it returns the highest `Zip` value

```
zippopinc$Zip[which.max(zippopinc$Poptoincomeratio)]
#[1] 612
```

Comment: Thanks.This is just a reproducible example and not the entire dataset, that is why you dont see 4.454182 @Ronak Shah. I mentioned #Repex.

Comment: @KidCode I know. Can you run `zippopinc$Zip[which.max(zippopinc$Poptoincomeratio)]` on your real data and compare the answer?

Comment: Yes, I got it and marked your answer correct. :) thanks