# Getting NaN instead of value by using a for loop in a triangular matrix in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I'm trying to assign the mean values from a data table (Ecoli) into a triangular matrix (Ecoli_matrix) by using a for loop. However, when the loop hit the index of 0.6 and 0.9 I get a NaN instead of the appropriate value.

I've tried different variations of the for loop and checked that all values are class numeric.

```
Ecoli_matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = 8, ncol = 8)
rownames(Ecoli_matrix) <- seq(0.3,1.0,0.1)
colnames(Ecoli_matrix) <- seq(0.3,1.0,0.1)
Ecoli_matrix[lower.tri(Ecoli_matrix)] <- NA

nums <- as.numeric(seq(0.3,1.0,0.1))
for (i in 1:8) {
  a <- nums[i]
  for (j in 1:8) {
    b <- nums[j]
    if (!is.na(Ecoli_matrix[i,j])) {
      Ecoli_matrix[i,j] <- mean(Ecoli[completeness_1 == a & completeness_2 == b]$ANI) 
    }else{
      next
    }
  }
}

Ecoli_matrix
```

Expected results:
real mean values instead of NaN

```
         0.3      0.4      0.5 0.6      0.7      0.8 0.9   1
0.3 98.53066 98.45858 98.98962 NaN 99.25422 99.64324 NaN 100
0.4       NA 98.87488 99.03502 NaN 99.34984 99.74074 NaN 100
0.5       NA       NA 99.31126 NaN 99.57964 99.72836 NaN 100
0.6       NA       NA       NA NaN      NaN      NaN NaN NaN
0.7       NA       NA       NA  NA 99.71534 99.85268 NaN 100
0.8       NA       NA       NA  NA       NA 99.90262 NaN 100
0.9       NA       NA       NA  NA       NA       NA NaN NaN
1         NA       NA       NA  NA       NA       NA  NA 100
```

Ecoli table:

```
 completeness_1 completeness_2      ANI
            0.3            0.3  97.9607
            0.3            0.4  98.8787
            0.3            0.5  99.2944
            0.3            0.6  98.8600
            0.3            0.7  99.1515
            0.3            0.8  99.7849
            0.3            0.9  99.5993
            0.3            1.0 100.0000
            0.3            0.3  98.4126
            0.3            0.4  98.3872
            0.3            0.5  98.5145
            0.3            0.6  99.4992
            0.3            0.7  99.4004
            0.3            0.8  99.6906
            0.3            0.9  99.8292
            0.3            1.0 100.0000
            0.3            0.3  99.1003
            0.3            0.4  98.4184
            0.3            0.5  99.3127
            0.3            0.6  98.8290
            0.3            0.7  99.3498
            0.3            0.8  99.6751
            0.3            0.9  99.8596
            0.3            1.0 100.0000
            0.3            0.3  98.6554
            0.3            0.4  97.9706
            0.3            0.5  98.5052
            0.3            0.6  99.3553
            0.3            0.7  99.2609
            0.3            0.8  99.4636
            0.3            0.9  99.7513
            0.3            1.0 100.0000
            0.3            0.3  98.5243
            0.3            0.4  98.6380
            0.3            0.5  99.3213
            0.3            0.6  99.2216
            0.3            0.7  99.1085
            0.3            0.8  99.6020
            0.3            0.9  99.8939
            0.3            1.0 100.0000
            0.4            0.3  98.9680
            0.4            0.4  99.1399
            0.4            0.5  99.0710
            0.4            0.6  99.1930
            0.4            0.7  99.5270
            0.4            0.8  99.7888
            0.4            0.9  99.8802
            0.4            1.0 100.0000
            0.4            0.3  98.1257
            0.4            0.4  98.4355
            0.4            0.5  98.7498
            0.4            0.6  99.2367
            0.4            0.7  99.2529
            0.4            0.8  99.7091
            0.4            0.9  99.7455
            0.4            1.0 100.0000
            0.4            0.3  98.5192
            0.4            0.4  98.9832
            0.4            0.5  99.1183
            0.4            0.6  99.2549
            0.4            0.7  99.0702
            0.4            0.8  99.7385
            0.4            0.9  99.8020
            0.4            1.0 100.0000
            0.4            0.3  98.8609
            0.4            0.4  99.1154
            0.4            0.5  99.2910
            0.4            0.6  99.5090
            0.4            0.7  99.3003
            0.4            0.8  99.6992
            0.4            0.9  99.7460
            0.4            1.0 100.0000
            0.4            0.3  98.7781
            0.4            0.4  98.7004
            0.4            0.5  98.9450
            0.4            0.6  99.2914
            0.4            0.7  99.5988
            0.4            0.8  99.7681
            0.4            0.9  99.8564
            0.4            1.0 100.0000
            0.5            0.3  99.1444
            0.5            0.4  99.3652
            0.5            0.5  99.6018
            0.5            0.6  99.5122
            0.5            0.7  99.7143
            0.5            0.8  99.6552
            0.5            0.9  99.8233
            0.5            1.0 100.0000
            0.5            0.3  99.1689
            0.5            0.4  99.3622
            0.5            0.5  99.2013
            0.5            0.6  99.4480
            0.5            0.7  99.7191
            0.5            0.8  99.7735
            0.5            0.9  99.8405
            0.5            1.0 100.0000
            0.5            0.3  98.7547
            0.5            0.4  99.0458
            0.5            0.5  99.1784
            0.5            0.6  99.5908
            0.5            0.7  99.3255
            0.5            0.8  99.6829
            0.5            0.9  99.8085
            0.5            1.0 100.0000
            0.5            0.3  98.8526
            0.5            0.4  99.4464
            0.5            0.5  99.1989
            0.5            0.6  99.6929
            0.5            0.7  99.6149
            0.5            0.8  99.8013
            0.5            0.9  99.8748
            0.5            1.0 100.0000
            0.5            0.3  99.0085
            0.5            0.4  98.3852
            0.5            0.5  99.3759
            0.5            0.6  99.2256
            0.5            0.7  99.5244
            0.5            0.8  99.7289
            0.5            0.9  99.9002
            0.5            1.0 100.0000
            0.6            0.3  98.8855
            0.6            0.4  99.1283
            0.6            0.5  99.3423
            0.6            0.6  99.3840
            0.6            0.7  99.6955
            0.6            0.8  99.7013
            0.6            0.9  99.7296
            0.6            1.0 100.0000
            0.6            0.3  99.0861
            0.6            0.4  99.5717
            0.6            0.5  99.4429
            0.6            0.6  99.5169
            0.6            0.7  99.7044
            0.6            0.8  99.9558
            0.6            0.9  99.7909
            0.6            1.0 100.0000
            0.6            0.3  99.3989
            0.6            0.4  99.4521
            0.6            0.5  99.5094
            0.6            0.6  99.6623
            0.6            0.7  99.6799
            0.6            0.8  99.8384
            0.6            0.9  99.9410
            0.6            1.0 100.0000
            0.6            0.3  99.1774
            0.6            0.4  99.2779
            0.6            0.5  99.4602
            0.6            0.6  99.4447
            0.6            0.7  99.5277
            0.6            0.8  99.7600
            0.6            0.9  99.7568
            0.6            1.0 100.0000
            0.6            0.3  99.6414
            0.6            0.4  99.3121
            0.6            0.5  99.6987
            0.6            0.6  99.6514
            0.6            0.7  99.6481
            0.6            0.8  99.9006
            0.6            0.9  99.9636
            0.6            1.0 100.0000
            0.7            0.3  99.4547
            0.7            0.4  99.6649
            0.7            0.5  99.6927
            0.7            0.6  99.5586
            0.7            0.7  99.7189
            0.7            0.8  99.9507
            0.7            0.9  99.8915
            0.7            1.0 100.0000
            0.7            0.3  99.7365
            0.7            0.4  99.5755
            0.7            0.5  99.4170
            0.7            0.6  99.6824
            0.7            0.7  99.6474
            0.7            0.8  99.8268
            0.7            0.9  99.9137
            0.7            1.0 100.0000
            0.7            0.3  99.6652
            0.7            0.4  99.6749
            0.7            0.5  99.6315
            0.7            0.6  99.6506
            0.7            0.7  99.7673
            0.7            0.8  99.7651
            0.7            0.9  99.8527
            0.7            1.0 100.0000
            0.7            0.3  99.2376
            0.7            0.4  99.5145
            0.7            0.5  99.5446
            0.7            0.6  99.5321
            0.7            0.7  99.6898
            0.7            0.8  99.7904
            0.7            0.9  99.8675
            0.7            1.0 100.0000
            0.7            0.3  99.3614
            0.7            0.4  99.4177
            0.7            0.5  99.5746
            0.7            0.6  99.6963
            0.7            0.7  99.7533
            0.7            0.8  99.9304
            0.7            0.9  99.8797
            0.7            1.0 100.0000
            0.8            0.3  99.7806
            0.8            0.4  99.7076
            0.8            0.5  99.7752
            0.8            0.6  99.6750
            0.8            0.7  99.8162
            0.8            0.8  99.8961
            0.8            0.9  99.9088
            0.8            1.0 100.0000
            0.8            0.3  99.8302
            0.8            0.4  99.6818
            0.8            0.5  99.7987
            0.8            0.6  99.7489
            0.8            0.7  99.8682
            0.8            0.8  99.8810
            0.8            0.9  99.8724
            0.8            1.0 100.0000
            0.8            0.3  99.4582
            0.8            0.4  99.6642
            0.8            0.5  99.7310
            0.8            0.6  99.7085
            0.8            0.7  99.8668
            0.8            0.8  99.8890
            0.8            0.9  99.9545
            0.8            1.0 100.0000
            0.8            0.3  99.4662
            0.8            0.4  99.5455
            0.8            0.5  99.7426
            0.8            0.6  99.8504
            0.8            0.7  99.7353
            0.8            0.8  99.9202
            0.8            0.9  99.9057
            0.8            1.0 100.0000
            0.8            0.3  99.7896
            0.8            0.4  99.7198
            0.8            0.5  99.9195
            0.8            0.6  99.7826
            0.8            0.7  99.8543
            0.8            0.8  99.9268
            0.8            0.9  99.9266
            0.8            1.0 100.0000
            0.9            0.3  99.9185
            0.9            0.4  99.8778
            0.9            0.5 100.0000
            0.9            0.6  99.9429
            0.9            0.7  99.8414
            0.9            0.8  99.9964
            0.9            0.9 100.0000
            0.9            1.0 100.0000
            0.9            0.3  99.8731
            0.9            0.4  99.7531
            0.9            0.5  99.8569
            0.9            0.6  99.8611
            0.9            0.7  99.9492
            0.9            0.8  99.9215
            0.9            0.9  99.9877
            0.9            1.0 100.0000
            0.9            0.3  99.9271
            0.9            0.4  99.8416
            0.9            0.5  99.7653
            0.9            0.6  99.8329
            0.9            0.7  99.9639
            0.9            0.8 100.0000
            0.9            0.9  99.9718
            0.9            1.0 100.0000
            0.9            0.3  99.9071
            0.9            0.4  99.9764
            0.9            0.5  99.9424
            0.9            0.6  99.9093
            0.9            0.7 100.0000
            0.9            0.8  99.9932
            0.9            0.9  99.9669
            0.9            1.0 100.0000
            0.9            0.3  99.7999
            0.9            0.4  99.8924
            0.9            0.5  99.8942
            0.9            0.6  99.9287
            0.9            0.7  99.9513
            0.9            0.8  99.9862
            0.9            0.9 100.0000
            0.9            1.0 100.0000
            1.0            0.3 100.0000
            1.0            0.4 100.0000
            1.0            0.5 100.0000
            1.0            0.6 100.0000
            1.0            0.7 100.0000
            1.0            0.8 100.0000
            1.0            0.9 100.0000
            1.0            1.0 100.0000
            1.0            0.3 100.0000
            1.0            0.4 100.0000
            1.0            0.5 100.0000
            1.0            0.6 100.0000
            1.0            0.7 100.0000
            1.0            0.8 100.0000
            1.0            0.9 100.0000
            1.0            1.0 100.0000
            1.0            0.3 100.0000
            1.0            0.4 100.0000
            1.0            0.5 100.0000
            1.0            0.6 100.0000
            1.0            0.7 100.0000
            1.0            0.8 100.0000
            1.0            0.9 100.0000
            1.0            1.0 100.0000
            1.0            0.3 100.0000
            1.0            0.4 100.0000
            1.0            0.5 100.0000
            1.0            0.6 100.0000
            1.0            0.7 100.0000
            1.0            0.8 100.0000
            1.0            0.9 100.0000
            1.0            1.0 100.0000
            1.0            0.3 100.0000
            1.0            0.4 100.0000
            1.0            0.5 100.0000
            1.0            0.6 100.0000
            1.0            0.7 100.0000
            1.0            0.8 100.0000
            1.0            0.9 100.0000
            1.0            1.0 100.0000
```

Comment: can you add `Ecoli`? We can't reproduce your code otherwise

Comment: Yes, it's now on the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error has something to do, how floats are saved in R. In short: when you create a sequence, you are not getting flat values. You can check this with `options(digits=20)` and then check the output of `nums`. By using the equal operator `==` those values are not equal in something like the 18th. or 19th. decimal position. A workaround is rounding the sequential `nums`.

```
for(i in 1:8){
  for (j in 1:8){
    if(!is.na(Ecoli_matrix[i,j])){
      Ecoli_matrix[i,j]<-mean(Ecoli[Ecoli$completeness_1 == round(nums[i],2) & Ecoli$completeness_2 == round(nums[j],2),]$ANI)
    }
  }
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) is a link to related problem which explains it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

A possible source of error could be that when comparing two doubles with `==` there are no matches. See: [Numeric comparison difficulty in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769510/numeric-comparison-difficulty-in-r). A way of avoiding this problem is to cast the double columns and the vector `nums` to a character type.

Since you are using `data.table`, you could try a more data.table-like approach:

```
cols = c("completeness_1", "completeness_2")
Ecoli[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = cols]
Ecoli_means <- Ecoli[, .(ANI_mean = mean(ANI)), by = cols]
```

And then you could reshape the result `Ecoli_means` into a triangular matrix if needed.